# Use array objects to print out in JS event listening

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

This code should take values from the array to be used in the events.
How can I achieve that?

Instead what I have working is a duplication of code to use in events and print the given values.

This is what works:

```
const eventConfig = require('./config').events

const util = require('util');

function x() {
    this.z = 'Hello world';

}


util.inherits(x, EventEmitter)


x.prototype.y = function(event1, event2 ) {
    console.log(this.z + ' ' + event1, event2);
    this.emit(eventConfig.foo, event1, event2)
}


const greeter1 = new x();

x1.on(eventConfig.foo, function(event1, event2){
    console.log('message: ' + event1, event2)
})

x1.y('Tony', 'liam');
```

This is what I am trying to make work

```
const eventConfig = require('./config').events

const util = require('util');

function x() {
    this.z = 'Hello world';

}
moethods and properties
util.inherits(x, EventEmitter)

let arguments = ['Tony', 'liam']

x.prototype.y = function(arguments) {
    console.log(this.z);
    this.emit(eventConfig.foo, + arguments)
}

const x1 = new x();

x1.on(eventConfig.foo, function(arguments){
    console.log('message: ' + arguments)
})

x1.y(arguments);
```

expected result:

```
message: Tony, Liam
```

received result:

```
message: NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo mistake

```
const util = require('util');

function x() {
    this.z = 'Hello world';

}
moethods and properties
util.inherits(x, EventEmitter)

let arguments = ['Tony', 'liam']

x.prototype.y = function(arguments) {
    console.log(this.z);
    //this.emit is an object taking 2 arguments. I was trying to concatenate them
    this.emit(eventConfig.foo, arguments)
}

const x1 = new x();

x1.on(eventConfig.foo, function(arguments){
    console.log('message: ' + arguments)
})

x1.y(arguments);
```